# Requiring properties in array of hash without looping in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hashmap, require

In Rails 4.2, I'd like to validate that every hash of an array passed as a parameter to my action has certain attributes.

For now I could only find how to filter out unwanted attributes, such as:

```
ActionController::Parameters.new(
    points: [{lat: 42, foo: 0}, {lng: 43, bar: 100}]
).permit(
    points: [:lat, :lng]
)
# => {"points"=>[{"lat"=>42}, {"lng"=>43}]}
```

What I'd like to do is making sure every member of `points` has both `lat` and `lng` without having to loop over it. Is this possible using `permit` or a similar method?

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called `require` that has the same signature as `permit`:

```
params.require(:lat, :lng)
```

Note that you can chain this with `permit`

Also, you can use `select` or `reject` on the params hash, secure params is mostly sugar for this anyway.

```
def my_params
  required_attrs = %w{lat lng}
  missing_params = required_attrs.select do |key|
    params.has_key?(key)
  end
  missing_params.empty? ? params : raise(RuntimeError, "missing params: #{missing_params.join(",")}")
end
```

Comment: `require` doesn't accept multiple arguments or work on nested attributes, let alone in an array. Your `my_params` method (or any other variant checking the presence of the keys) works, but it still requires me to loop over the `points` array

Comment: Your desire to avoid a loop seems like premature optimization. Even if you find some abstraction, I'm almost certain it will still use a loop under the hood. You have an array and need to check each element of it - this is O(N) time at least (and thus a loop). Also, from the docs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require) is an example using `require` with multiple arguments.

Comment: This was more about making sure something for this didn't already exist rather than optimization. Thank you though!